# Non-blocking Dialog box in Applescript

Tags: dialog, applescript, nonblocking

I have to write a small script to deploy a patch for our Application. The patch 
will replace a couple of files in the application.I decided to depploy the patch using Applescript. The files to be copied are quite large and it takes some time for the files to be copied. I wanted to know if there is any way I can get a dialog box which doesn't block the execution of the script so that I can display some message like Updating.. etc while the patch is applied and then close the dialog box after wards.

Thanks
Shivaprasad

Answer (score 1):

There's a scripting addition called Akua Sweets (oldy but goody) that has a **display progress** command. Get it at osaxen.com. it's in the 'most popular' section at the top of the page.

**edit**
Oh, bugger, that's only for OS9. It was really useful back in the day, I remember using it a lot (of course everything took a lot longer in those days so progress bars were more in demand).

**another edit**
You got me inspired, there's a couple of scripts I use that need progress bars, so I went looking and found this scripting addition at http://osaxen.com/files/extrasuites1.1.html

**and again**
[here's a basic tutorial](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.01/ProgressFeedback/index.html) for how to do it in interface builder. I think that's probably the *right* way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I myself ran into the same problem.  Unfortunately applescript doesn't provide an easy way of implementing a progress bar.

I ended up using the stop loop example found [here](http://www.jonn8.com/html/misc_projects.html) to build an application.  This guy has a bunch of applescript studio xcode projects to download and mess around with.  It's some really great sample code if you aren't too familiar with applescript studio.