# Applescript Shell Script Progress

Tags: shell, applescript, progress

I am creating an applescript that creates a backup image of the /Users folder in Mac Os X. I would like to do one of two things:

1. Either display a barber pole progress bar while the shell script is running with an option to quit.
2. Display a dialog box while the script is running with an option to quit.

I have tried doing the shell script with the /dev/null but that ignores all output. I would like to save the output and display it in a dialog for the user.

Here is my code:

```
set computername to (do shell script "networksetup -getcomputername")
set fin to ""
set theIcon to note
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set folderalias to "/Users"
        set foldersize to physical size of folder (alias ":Users") --(info for folderalias) 
        set foldersize to (round ((foldersize / 1.0E+9) * 100)) / 100
    on error
        tell application "System Events"
            set foldersize to (round (((get physical size of folder ":Users" as text) / 1.0E+9) * 100)) / 100
        end tell
    end try
end tell

display dialog "User profile backup utility" & return & return & ¬
    "The computer name is: " & computername & return & return & ¬
    "The '/Users/' directory size is: " & "~" & foldersize & " GB" & return & return & ¬
    "Would you like to backup the '/User' directory now?" & return ¬
    buttons {"Cancel", "Backup Now"} default button "Backup Now"
set comd to "hdiutil create ~/Desktop/" & computername & ".dmg -srcfolder /test/"
set fin to do shell script (comd) with administrator privileges
display dialog fin
```

Comment: What if I did the shell script with the output to /dev/null and grab the PID from the shell script. Then I can kill the process with a button?? 

How would I go about doing that (if possible)?

Comment: That is another question entirely – not to turn you down, but on Stack Overflow, you expected to ask different questions quite literally as different questions, so as not to turn questions into multi-issue discussion threads. Even if the questions all relate to the same code :).

Comment: quite willing to take a crack at it if you do ask, BTW – it’s an interesting question :).

Comment: I've written an tutorial here (well someone else posted it for me) http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=34563. It was originally written for Studio application but can be used with AppleScript's of course.

Comment: Comment thread morphed into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542771/using-asobjc-runner-to-abort-a-shell-script-command-in-applescript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Displaying a progress bar dialog is not possible with on-board AppleScript (i.e. *Standard Additions*), but  this can be achieved using [Shane Stanley’s *ASObjC Runner*](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner.html), a scriptable faceless background application which provides, among many over useful functions, a set of progress dialog related commands. Once downloaded onto your system,

```
tell application "ASObjC Runner"
    reset progress
    set properties of progress window to {button title:"Abort Backup", button visible:true, message:"Backing up the '" & (POSIX path of folderalias) & "' directory.", detail:"There are " & foldersize & " GB of data to backup – this might take some time.", indeterminate:true}
    activate
    show progress
end tell
try -- to make sure we destroy the dialog even if the script error out
    <your backup operation here>
end try   
tell application "ASObjC Runner" to hide progress
```

will show an indeterminate progress bar (or “barber pole”) while the backup operation runs – at least if it is synchronous (as shell commands called from AS are). As to the output of your shell command, that is automatically returned by the `do shell script` command – in your code, it is assigned to `fin` [code lifted more or less wholesale from the [ASObjC Runner documentation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner_vanilla.html)].

*ASObjC Runner* can be embedded into an AppleScript application (save your script as an application in *AppleScript Editor*) by putting it into the bundle’s `Resources` folder (in Finder, select *Show Package Contents* in the context menu) and using the [`path to resource` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW20) to call it inside a [`using terms from` block](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-SW3) – the documentation I linked to above has details and example code, but, crucially, contains one critical error: your `tell` statement [needs to use the POSIX path to the Resources bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW2) (`tell application (POSIX path of (path to resource "ASObjC Runner.app"))`).

**A few remarks on your code:**

- there is a more elegant way to get an alias to the `/Users` folder:

  ```
  path to users folder
  ```

  – no need for hardwiring and calls to *Finder*. You can then get the shell compatible path to that by using `POSIX path of`, or, if you need it quoted, `quoted form of POSIX path of` of it.
- I’d recommend using only *System Events* to get the `physical size` – unlike *Finder*, it works in the background. That will allow you to get rid of the `tell application "Finder"` and `try … catch` blocks (not sure what you meant to achieve by that one anyway – if you were reacting to `error -10004`, that is because `round` does not like to be put inside a `tell` block).
- No need to initialize `fin` to an empty string – you will get a return value from `do shell script`.
- Speaking of your `do shell script`, you need to quote the `computerName` variable of it will break on spaces in that name.
- `theIcon` is never used.
- You might want to use `display alert` instead of `display dialog` for the user confirmation, as it has a nice emphasis on the first part of the message.
- There are a lot of unnecessary parentheses in the code – AppleScript needs some of these to delimit semantic command blocks, but not all of them…

All together mean your code can be modified to:

```
set computerName to do shell script "networksetup -getcomputername"
set folderAlias to path to users folder
tell application "System Events" to set folderSize to physical size of folderAlias
set folderSize to round(folderSize / 1.0E+9 * 100) / 100

display alert "User profile backup utility" message ¬
  "The computer name is: " & computerName & return & return & ¬
  "The '" & (POSIX path of folderAlias) & "' directory size is: " & "~" & folderSize & " GB" & return & return & ¬
  "Would you like to backup the '" & (POSIX path of folderAlias) & "' directory now?" & return ¬
  buttons {"Cancel", "Backup Now"} default button "Backup Now"
set shellCmd to "hdiutil create ~/Desktop/'" & computerName & "'.dmg -srcfolder /test/"
-- progress bar dialog display initialization goes here
try
    set shellOutput to do shell script shellCmd with administrator privileges
end try
-- progress bar dialog hiding goes here
display dialog shellOutput
```

Comment: Thank you for the code suggestions. It does clean it up a significant amount. 

I am running this on numerous machines and do not want to have to copy over and run the ASObjC Runner app on each one. I just need a easy way to show that its working or at least have a dialog open while it is working.

Comment: @JohnnyHieuLe: you can embed the *ASObjC Runner* application in your AppleScript, if you distribute it as a Script application – the Readme to the application contains instructions for that. Also, it wil run all by itself when called via `tell`. If you don’t want that, you are out of luck as to AppleScript – *Standard Additions* dialogs are all blocking (i.e., they wait for a button click before relinquishing flow control back to the script). [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068181/non-blocking-dialog-box-in-applescript) – the situation hasn’t improved much since then.

Comment: Great if I can run it in the application than that will work for me. I will give it a try and see how it goes. Thanks so much!!!

Now my problem is that I want to save the script as an application and be able to run it on a 10.5 machine. I am running 10.7 and when I save the script as a run only application it does not work on the 10.5 machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnnyHieuLe: Lion’s AppleScript Editor generates 64 bit executables. You’ll have to save the script as an application on the Leopard machine.

Comment: Comment thread morphed into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540995/applescript-universal-application).

Comment: @kopischke I tried embeding the ASObjC Runner as described on the webpage but I keep getting a resource not found. I put the app in the resources folder and set property to path to resouce "ASObjC Runner-N.app" as text like the sample describes but I still get the error??

Answer (score 1):

Although not as pretty as kopischke's suggestion, a quick and dirty way to get progress information is to run the command in the terminal itself.

```
set comd to "hdiutil create -puppetstrings '~/Desktop/" & computername & ".dmg' -srcfolder '/test/'"
tell application "Terminal" to do script comd
```