# Applescript Universal application

Tags: applescript, universal

Is there a way for me to create an Applescript as a run only application that would work on 10.5 and above?

I am running Lion. Whenever I save my script as a run only application it does not work with 10.5 and gives me a "does not work with this architecture" error.

The weird thing is that I saved it once and successfully launched it on the 10.5 machine but when I went to edit it and re-save it did not work anymore.

Thx

Comment: Does it work in 10.5 from the Script Editor?

Comment: Out of interest: are you sure your 10.5 machine is an Intel Mac? Leopard was the last version of OS X to run on PowerPC machines… If it is, try copying the script to it and creating the application on it. That should give you a 32 bit Intel binary that will run on Leopard, Snow Leopard *and Lion.

Comment: @adayzdone Yes it does work from the script editor.

Comment: @kopischke I did that but would like to avoid it, but if I can't than I will just continue to do so. Thanks!

Comment: @kopischke little correction: You mean that PPC isn't supported after SL. Script editor in SL still saves three architecturs: PPC, i386 and x86_64. In Lion PPC is not supported anymore.

Comment: @djbazziewazzie: correct – but no, I meant OP’s 10.5 machine might be PPC (as 10.5 was the last OS version to support that architecture, AFAIK), which Lion’s AS Editor does not cater for.

Comment: @kopischke Ah I see. I thought you meant that Leopard was the only OS to save PPC binaries with script editor. However my advise would be to use SL when possible. In Leopard you save only 2 binaries (32-bit intel and PPC) while SL saves 3 binaries (32- and 64-bit intel and PPC G4 and newer).

Comment: @djbazziewazzie: good to know. But Lion should run the 32 bit binary, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @kopischke If you save it as an application it would run the 64-bit binary in SL and Lion. If you're using scripting additions that requires that the script run in 32-bit mode (and still assuming you saved the script as an application) you should check the 'open in 32-bit mode' in the finder.

Comment: @djbazziewazzie I missed a “ be able to” back there, as in “but Lion should be able to run the 32 bit binary”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and Apple's documentation isn't clear. My experience, based on a lot of trial and error, has been that when saving an Applescript as an application, that it has to be saved in the target environment, just as though you were targeting a specific OS when compiling for Xcode. In the past, I have had to make separate apps for 10.6 and 10.7 as well as PowerPC and Intel with the exact same code inside.